# Subir un proyecto Web C# y alojarlo en otro sitio

Tags: web, servidor, ssl, dominio, upload

soy nuevo en el manejo de servidores necesito subir un proyecto Web que hice en vs2015 C# MVC.

El detalle es que tengo un sitio de donde el va a ser invocado. 
Ejemplo: www.miindex.com. Aqui va haber un enlace para llamar a mi sitio  (Portal) y deberia de quedar asi www.miindex.com/**portal** y asi quedaria la url con mi proyecto abierto.

Como se hace eso? pense que solo era crear una carpeta en la raiz y copiar mi proyecto y nada.

Espero y me ayuden, Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Lo resolví. Era que no tenia Habilitada la característica de IIS para ejecutar aplicaciones ASP, Me fui al **Panel de control**->**Programas**->**Programas y Características** ->**Activar o desactivar Características de Windows**, Seleccione **Internet Information Services** [image: En mi caso estos fueron los que habilite y luego Aceptar]

Comment: ¡Felicitaciones bro! Lo lograste :D sigue así, elevando ese cosmos y dándole con todo el power 2.0!!! En 24 horas marcas tu respuesta como aceptada, de tal manera que la salud del sitio se mantiene buena (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos

Comment: Gracias por Animarme, Saludos desde Nicaragua

Comment: de nada bro! para eso estamos, estás en la hermandad de SOes, entre todos nos apoyamos